# Kobold2D game compilation error

Tags: dependencies, kobold2d, apportable

I'm porting my iPhone app from iOS to android, and I'm struggling to build on my android device. My app uses the Kobold2D library, and when I run apportable load my build fails and the error says to check dependencies.

In order to run my kobold2d game in xcode, I have to open the kobold2D workspace, then run my game from within there. When I don't, the same error occurs in xcode as apportable is giving me.

Does anybody know how to get apportable to recognize my library and connect it to my game?